# Flow screen Long text area field isn't written in SObject

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a field in a screen flow of type Long Text Area. This field is set by the user and must be written in a Long Text Area field in an SObject record when the user validates the screen. The screen field takes its default value from a Text Template Flow variable. All actions are performed in 1 flow. The Long Text Area screen field is assigned to the SObejct Long Text Area field in the Create Records component.

Everything works fine. But when I test the writing of the Screen data in the SObject, the Long Text Area field is not written.

The weird thing is that the Flow Debugger shows a successful assignment of the Screen field into the SObject field.

[image]

Am I missing something or is it a limitation (or something worst) in Flow ?